# MongoDB Driver and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I want to use the Ruby MongoDb driver directly in a rails 3 application with out an ORM.  Can some one provide a sample?  I am new to rails so the more detail the better.

Thanks

Comment: "the more detail the better."  same for you. This is just too broad.

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form"

Comment: What have you searched on and read so far?

Answer (score 0):

I started to use MongoDB Ruby driver a few months ago and I can relate to the lack of documentation about it.
My first recommendation would be to check-out this page which provide some use cases:

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

Apart from this you should try to execute your queries from your MongoDB provider interface (Mongolab for instance).